# Where does logstash's elasticsearch index date come from?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

From [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index):

```
Default value is "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
```

I'm wondering where logstash gets the information for YYYY.MM.dd? Is it the @timestamp field? And if so, can it be told to use a different field (@mydate, for example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index YYYY.MM.dd is according to the @timestamp time.

You can refer to [elasticsearch.rb](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb#L308) about the 'event.sprintf' to print the logstash index.

```
index = event.sprintf(@index)
```

and then you can study [event.rb](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/lib/logstash/event.rb#L223) to see what the sprintf do.

```
t = @data["@timestamp"]
    formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(key[1 .. -1])\
      .withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone::UTC)
    #next org.joda.time.Instant.new(t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000).toDateTime.toString(formatter)
    # Invoke a specific Instant constructor to avoid this warning in JRuby
    #  > ambiguous Java methods found, using org.joda.time.Instant(long)
    org.joda.time.Instant.java_class.constructor(Java::long).new_instance(
      t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000
    ).to_java.toDateTime.toString(formatter)
```

So, If you want the index follow your own field, you have to modify the event.rb to use your own field instead of timestamp. Or you can change the timestamp value to your own field time.